# curl with basic http auth not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to connect to a WS using curl.
My code :

```
$url ="https://example?param=ee&param2=rr";
$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("username:password") // <---
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:passwrd');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

I get this error:

> ```
>  'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0, 
>  'request_size' => 0, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 0, 
>  'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 0.051353999999999997, 
>  'namelookup_time' => 0.0032659999999999998, 
>  'connect_time' => 0.051365000000000001, 'pretransfer_time' => 0,
>  'size_upload' => 0, 'size_download' => 0, 'speed_download' => 0,
>  'speed_upload' => 0, 'download_content_length' => -1, 
>  'upload_content_length' => -1, 'starttransfer_time' => 0, 
>  'redirect_time' => 0, 'certinfo' => array ( ), 
>  'primary_ip' => '185.18.224.30', 'primary_port' => 443, 
>  'local_ip' => '172.23.155.94', 'local_port' => 44608, 
>  'redirect_url' => '', )error occured during curl exec.
> ```

I can't figure out the error in my code. Have a missed a parameter?

Comment: by WS do you mean website, rather than a .ws site?

Comment: Any reason you are not using CURLOPT_USERPWD, instead of assembling the authorization header yourself?

Comment: it's set on the headers array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

By default when you use HTTPS protocol, CURL checks SSL sertificate on your server and gives an error if it is not valid. The line above turns this off.

Comment: While this could be correct, it's worth noting that it's extremely bad practise to turn off cURL verification as the TLS secured site might as well not be secured if it can't be authenticated. (Fixing this Verification is probably another issue, however). [reference](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url ="https://example?";
            $headers = array(
                                'Content-Type:application/json',
                                'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("username:password") 
                            );
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"param=ee&param2=rr");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);   

          // execute the request

            $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: can you edit you answer and explain what you changed and why your code works?

Comment: thx but I'm I'm using get method so I don't need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`